# Why do I have to double-press alt/option to get a meta key?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, aquamacs

I'm using Aquamacs 3.3  GNU Emacs 25.1.1 under MacOSX 10.12.6 (Sierra).

It's a fresh install of the operating system and aquamacs. Instead of just doing option-g to get meta-g like I used to, I now have to do option-g option-g to get meta-g. This is annoying.

Anyone come across this problem and solved it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aquamacs does not read ~/.emacs.d/init.el?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/why-aquamacs-does-not-read-emacs-d-init-el)  The vote to close is based upon the answer by the original poster indicating this question is actually related to the possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The actual root cause of the problem was that aquamacs only loads `~/.emacs` and not `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

Having moved my `.emacs` to the right place, the following config took effect as expected: `(global-set-key [(meta g)] 'goto-line)`